# exec, execSync, spawn and spawnSync fail when not supplied with stdio: 'inherit' as config

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I am working on a node script to interface with digitalocean's container registry.

To begin with, I tried to get the script running with basic commands such as `doctl registry get`. I ran into problems almost immediately:

Take the following code (which works):

```js
// this works
execSync('doctl registry get', { stdio: 'inherit' })

console.log('\n')

// so does this
spawnSync('doctl', ['registry', 'get'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
```

Output:

```
Name                  Endpoint
redacted              registry.digitalocean.com/redacted


Name                  Endpoint
redacted              registry.digitalocean.com/redacted
```

This is fine, however I want to capture the output of commands in the code so that I can write logic around them. I thought I would be able to do this by omitting `{ stdio: 'inherit' }`, however this causes problems:

```js
// this does not work
const result = execSync('doctl registry get')

console.log('result: ', result)
```

Output:

```
child_process.js:655
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: doctl registry get
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:652:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/me/projects/path/to/script.js:31:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [], Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [] ],
  pid: 271969,
  stdout: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
  stderr: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] []
```

No information is given apart from the fact that `doctl registry get` failed. `stderr` and `stdout` are empty buffers. `spawn`, `exec`, and `spawnSync` all produce the same error

Consider another example using `spawn`:

```js
const testProc = spawn('doctl', ['registry', 'get'])

testProc.stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`)
})

testProc.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`)
})

testProc.on('close', code => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`)
})
```

Output:

```
child process exited with code 1
```

Again, the only information is that the command failed.

My question is: **why do these commands (`exec`, `spawn`, `spawnSync`, `execSync`) behave differently when `{ stdio: 'inherit' }` is povided as an option?**

The command succeeds when `{ stdio: 'inherit' }` is provided but fails when omitted. I do not understand why changing where the io streams go affects how the command functions.

---

Environment:

Node version: 14.16.0

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I can't replicate this. The latter example using `spawn` does print `stderr: Error: GET https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/registry: 404 registry does not exist` (I don't have any registries).

Comment: Which OS are you on, which version of Node.js are you running, etc.?

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Node 14.16.0